# How to remap “ctrl+w+shift+f” to “gf” in vim to go to line of file under cursor in split window?

Tags: key-bindings

In a compilation log file whenever I get error it shows full path from root directory and line number.

After opening file in vim say following is the content of file,

```
..
..
Dir1/Dir2/src/ipv4.c 1223
..
..
```

In vim in esc mode When I take cursor on above line and type <kbd>ctrl+w</kbd><kbd>shift+f</kbd> it will split the window horizontally and open file `ipv4.c` and take cursor to line number `1223`.

go to line  of file under cursor in split window. I want to set a small shortcut say `gf` which should be mapped to <kbd>ctrl+w</kbd><kbd>shift+f</kbd>.

So everytime typing <kbd>ctrl+w</kbd><kbd>shift+f</kbd> to do so is headache. So I want to map this to some custom shortcut say `gf` in `.vimrc` file. So How to do it?

Answer (score 7):

A simple mapping could do the trick. Add the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap gf <c-w>F
```

#### Thoughts

- May want to map `<c-w>F` to `gf` so that the functionality is swapped
- Maybe remap the window key, `<c-w>`, as that sounds like a pain point. e.g. `nnoremap <space> <c-w>`
- Use regular `gf` and use `<c-6>` or `<c-o>` to get back to the log file
- Set a upper case mark, e.g. `mM`, so that you can get back to the log file, e.g. `` `M ``
- May want this mapping to only apply to log files. Then add `nnoremap <buffer> gf <c-w>gF` to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` where `python` is your filetype.

For more help see:

```
:h gf
:h Ctrl-w_F
:h mapping
:h Ctrl-6
:h Ctrl-o
:h m
:h mark-motions
:h after-directory
:h ftplugin
```

Comment: thanks jamessan. I tried "nnoremap gf <c-w>gF" but its opening file in new tab. How to open it in horizontally split window rather than newtab.

Comment: Thanks I tried "nnoremap gf <C-w>F" and it solved my problem. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a direct answer to your question, because I wonder if Vim might already have a more comprehensive solution for your problem.

Vim has support for running a compilation process, opening the compilation output (in the QuickFix List), and jumping to lines where errors were reported.

#### Option 1

If you use a GNU Makefile, and you are in the same folder, then all you need to do to compile is type:

```
:make
```

#### Option 2

But if you compile in a different way, you should first tell Vim how:

```
:set makeprg=gcc\ file.c\ -o\ myapp

" Or to avoid escaping those spaces, you can instead do:

:let &makeprg="gcc file.c -o myapp"
```

And then you can compile using your specified method, by doing:

```
:make
```

#### Option 3

If you don't want to run the compilation from inside Vim, but you still want to open the logfile in the QuickFix List, then do this:

```
:cfile my_compilation.log
```

#### Viewing the errors

The QuickFix List is useful because it can recognise some error log formats, and help you to navigate them.  To step forwards or backwards through errors, use:

```
:cnext
:cprev
```

To view all the errors, open the QuickFix Window:

```
:copen
```

In that window you can jump to source of an error by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  To open in a newly split window, hit <kbd>Ctrl+W Enter</kbd>.

#### Further information

For more details on the whole process, see:

```
:help :make
:help 'makeprg'
:help quickfix
:help errorformat
```

Comment: If what the OP really wanted is to look at compilation errors then using `:make` and the quickfix is the way to go. Also take a look at `:compiler` for setting common different `'makeprg'` and `'errorformat'`'s (See `:h :compiler`). I also find it good to have nice mappings for `:cn`/`:cp`. I use Tim Pope's [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) which provide `]q` and `[q` respectively.